# Dirty hack for overlapping instances?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, overlapping-instances

Module A imports modules B and C

Module B imports instance X

Module C imports instance Y

X and Y are instances of a common type class.

Instances X and Y are identical in type, that is, fully overlapping.

When I use B or C separately, everything works. When I import them (here in A) to do some comparative testing (or benchmarking), I get an overlapping instances error inside C saying that both X and Y match.

This is puzzling to me as the only path from C to X is: `C -> A -> B`. Is this how it's supposed to be? Also, is there a way around this? I'm ok with dirty hacks as the two instances are never used together in normal circumstances. In particular, I don't want to introduce phantom types etc.

Comment: You don't need a path from C to X, you need a path from C and one from X to a common meeting place. That's A here. Instances are always exported, so in A, you have both instances in scope. The only sane way is to not have two instances of the same class for the same type. (If B and C are both yours, fix that! If one is yours and the other not, can you get rid of your instance and use the other? If neither is yours, poke the maintainers of the packages to resolve it in a sensible way.)

Comment: They are both mine and are just two alternative implementations which I both want to keep. I know that I can use phantom types to work around this, but in the end, that complicates matters and in my case leads to more noisy syntax (the type class is used as part of a DSL). In Scala one can choose which instances to import, so I thought there must be _some_ way.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what the class you have there looks like, it should be easy to fix this with two small proxy modules `P` and `Q`, each with the same `newtype ProxyXY` wrapper with `GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving` to the desired class; but one importing `module B` and the other importing `module C`, so they actually use the different instances. You then have two types `P.ProxyXY` and `Q.ProxyXY` that behave the same, but the former uses the X instance while the latter uses the Y instance of the underlying type.

(Not shure if that's what you meant with "Phantom types", but those are actually [something different](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type).)

Comment: Hmm, the class is `class Rewritable r a b where...` and I tried `newtype ProxyXY p = ProxyXY p deriving (Rewritable p)` but it says "Can't make a derived instance of 'Rewritable p (ProxyXY p)' (even with cunning newtype deriving): 'Rewritable p' does not have arity 1". By the way, is your answer related to [this](http://joyoftypes.blogspot.com/2012/02/haskell-supports-first-class-instances.html?showComment=1330615107602#c7037550684345333705)?

Comment: Perhaps you should have mentioned it's a MultiParam–type-class you're talking about! `GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving` doesn't work then. You can still write the proxy newtypes and define their instances by hand, but that's of course not going to be very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is not a serious answer, although it lets me compile my code.

I think GHC (7.4.1) or cabal has a bug. The first compilation fails with the stated overlapping instances error. But, doing it again (both times using `cabal-dev build`) it succeeds! I'll explain why:

The first compilation stopped while compiling C. So C and A were not compiled. Rerunning the compilation, first C is compiled, successfully, and then A. I guess C can be compiled now because GHC doesn't pick up the indirect instance from B (as C doesn't have a direct dependency to B, and A is compiled *after* C).

So, in the end, it's a problem caused by partial compilation, and indeed a very dirty hack for my problem.